# Detect current on intercom

Tags: arduino, pullup, pulldown

I'm trying to get an input from an intercom and apparently there is GND and another wire for the call. I'd like to know when there's voltage between the call wire and the ground.

I'm thinking of using the arduino's ground to pull current from the call. Is that possible? What is the best way to do this?

Maybe all I need is a transistor?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe all you need is a multimeter first, to check the voltages on the line. Do carefully check the voltage during ringing too. Without that information, nobody can help you. Coming to think of it, you probably have to be familiar with AC and DC measurements and the idea behind superposition. For the time being, I wouldn't connect an Arduino to that line.

Comment: I have a multimeter and can do the measurements. That line is idle now, but I can do the measurements with GND while ringing. I know for a fact that it's running a DC. What if the voltage/current is greater than what the arduino can take? How to basically sense that value and have that be a digital LOW or HIGH input? Thank you.

Comment: Set the dial of your multimeter in the volts range and measure the line in all thinkable situations. Idle, ringing, call. Both AC and DC. That is essential information that you'll have to add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Play safe and avoid your arduino being fryed by something you haven't noticed like: -

1. Maybe there are big spikes on the wire that your multimeter cannot detect
2. What appears to be ground on the intercom may be several volts different to GND on arduino
3. Worse than (2), where does the intercom get its power from - maybe it's OK maybe it's not - what sort of isolation to AC mains does it have - do you know? I can nearly smell burning just thinking about it!!

I'd use an opto coupler to detect the voltage you want. At least if you fry the opto you can just go and buy another and not get raging mad like I would if I'd fryed the main CPU due to my own carelessness.

Comment: This is the intercom receiver I'm willing to connect my arduino to www.bpt.it/docs/bptistr/bpt_yc200_200a-201 24067200 09_04.pdf